# Enable a Permission only when using Google Chrome Dev channel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there any way to only enable certain permissions when using the dev channel of Chrome? I want to use the "signedInDevices" API only if the user has the dev channel, since it is not in the beta and stable channels. I've tried putting it as an optional permission, but chrome still throws warnings.

Comment: If it is just a warning, why not just ignore it.?

Comment: Wouldn't the users see that there is an warning? I don't want them thinking there is a bug when there isn't one.